Tensor Product of Modules of Bialgebras
Lately I saw this post (in chinese) saying that the tensor product of modules relies on comultiplication, and the tensor product over a commutative algebra is a consequence of a canonical bialgebra structure on the commutative algebra.
This seems to make sense. For universal enveloping algebras of lie algebras, the action on tensor product of modules are given by differentiation $x \mapsto x \otimes Id + Id \otimes x$ , exactly the same as the canonical comultiplication. Similarly for group algebras.
However, I am not able to come up with a bialgebra structure over a commutative algebra, nor can I construct a tensor product over a category of modules over bialgebras. How to?
Moreover, how would this construction relate to the traditional tensor product, that is, defining $M \otimes_A N$ to be the coequalizer of the two maps $Id_M \otimes \mu_N, \mu_M \otimes Id_N: M \otimes A \otimes N \to M \otimes N$ where $M$ a right $A$-module, $N$ a left $A$-module, and $\mu_M,\mu_N$ the structural maps of $M$ and $N$?

Concerning the tensor product of modules over a bialgebra, that is the tensor product over the base field. You may refer to this or this post, for instance. Instead, concerning the canonical bialgebra structure on a commutative algebra, are you sure it is a bialgebra and not a bialgebroid structure? $\Bbbk[X]$ is a commutative algebra and it becomes a bialgebra with either the primitive-like or the group-like comultiplication, and none of them seems to me more canonical than the other.
